# Azure data factory - Copy Data activity Sink - Max rows per file property

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to spilt my big size file into smaller chunks inside blob storage via ADF copy data activity. I am trying to do so using **Max Rows per file** property in Copy activity sink but my file is not getting spilt into smaller files rather I get the same big size file in result, can anyone share any valuable info here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it, and it can work fine.

1. Source dataset

[image]

2.Source setting

[image]

3.Sink dataset

[image]

4.Sink setting

[image]

Result:
[image]